# Linking Libraries in VxWorks Debug and non Debug Modes

Tags: debugging, hyperlink, static-libraries, mode, vxworks

I have a static library that i can build in both Debug and NonDebug mode. I wish to use the Debug version in an RTP when i build the RTP with the Debug Mode option. I wish to use the Non Debug version in an RTP when i build the RTP with out the Debug option. All i can find, is to put the library name with the full path in the Library tab of the RTP project. The path contains the \Debug\ directory. I have to manually change it to \NonDebug\ when i change the build. I am looking for how to setup the project file to automatically select the appropriate path based on having Debug Mode checked or not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I solved using a local variable thats generate the vxworks at the makefile called MODE_DIR, that will be replace with "Debug" or "NonDebug"

So go to the **properties** of your RTP >> **Build Porperties** >> **Libraries**

and then at the path of your librariy, in this case "Example"

-L/Lib_output_path/Example/Example/$(MODE_DIR)

-lExample